# Does eclipse sdk has an adt bundle?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, adt

I am confuse with this if does eclipse SDK has an adt bundle that I can use in my Phonegap command line.

In phonegap For Cordova command-line tools to work, you need to include the SDK's tools and platform-tools directories in your PATH environment.

My current eclipse is this "eclipse-SDK-3.7.1-win32".

Answer (score 0):

You can visit [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) to download the newest ADT bundle with Eclipse. The stand alone Eclipse does not contain ADT Bundle. Please come to your Eclipse path and check if having "SDK" folder (same level with Eclipse folder), it means having an ADT bundle.